# Can't get php errors to show when `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`

Tags: php, wamp

I have WAMP with php 5.4.12 and I want to report errors.

My `php.ini` contains the following:

```
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
;   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

but no errors are showing.

What value should `error_reporting` take and how can I retrieve the reported errors?

Answer (score 3):

I guess `display_errors` is turned off in your php.ini. Try the following instead (in the php file you are working on).

```
ini_set('display_errors' , 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For setting the flag on from php.ini, locate where `display_errors` is and change the value to `On`. Post your full php.ini if this does not work.

Comment: I added in your code after error_reporting = E_ALL and now I get: Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.

Comment: I found it. (um feel a little silly) - error reporting turned off in back end... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether any error reporting flag in the php script(which will overwrite the php ini flags) in which you are trying to run and also in the .htaccess file. These are the two options which overwrites the php .ini flags.